# Is there a criterion for $S+T$ to be a subrng?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is a criterion for group

> Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$.
>
> Then, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $HK=KH$.

Just like this, I'm curious to know whether there is a similar criterion for rng

That is:

> Let $R$ be an rng and $S,T$ be subrngs of $R$.
>
> Is there a criterion for $S+T$ to be a subrng?

Comment: The fact that there are two operations makes it much less likely. For example, if
$$R=\mathbb{C}[x,y],\quad S=\mathbb{C}[x],\quad T=\mathbb{C}[y]$$
then $S+T$ is not a subring because it's not closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for $S+T$ to be a subring we must have that for every $s,s'\in S$ and $t,t'\in T$,

$$(s+t)(s'+t')=ss'+st'+ts'+tt'\in S+T$$

Since $ss'+tt'\in S+T$ and $S+T$ is closed under addition, the requirement is equivalent to saying that $st'+ts'\in S+T$ for all $s,s'\in S$ and $t,t'\in T$. Thus $S+T$ is a subring if and only if
$$ST+TS\subseteq S+T$$